# How do I integrate a form over a curve that is not smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I want to integrate some $df$ over this thing:

$$\gamma:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, t\mapsto (\sin^3(\frac{\pi t}{2}), \cos (\pi t))$$

Now this is apparently not smooth, so how can I compute the integral $\int_\gamma df$?

Comment: This is smooth.

Comment: @Pedro The image of this curve is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, it has a singular point at $t=0$.

Comment: So? It's still a smooth function, so we can pull back $df$ to get a smooth form in $[0, 1]$ which we integrate as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a manifold $M$, a one-form $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ and a smooth curve $\gamma \colon I \rightarrow M$, the integral of $\omega$ over $\gamma$ is defined as

$$ \int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_{[0,1]} \gamma^{*}(\omega). $$

This is well-defined irregardless of whether $\gamma$ is one-to-one, an immersion or a smooth embedding. If $\gamma$ is a smooth embedding, you can interpret the integral as

$$ \int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_{\gamma(I)} \omega|_{\gamma(I)} $$

so the integral of $\omega$ over $\gamma$ coincides with the integral of the restriction of the one-form $\omega$ to the image of $\gamma$ (a one-dimensional submanifold of $M$) over the image of $\gamma$.